# PHP/Laravel Select text in brackets after certain number

Tags: php, regex, text

We have a field in a database (of a Laravel 5.4 site) that has cells with data like this:

```
"123(Description of 123) 124(Description of 124) 125(Description of 125)"
```

All in one long string. I need to output the bracketed text but only of the specified number. For example, pass the number 123 as a parameter and Description of 123 is returned.

I have the regex pattern to use with preg_match that extracts the data from the brackets:

```
$sTest = "247(text goes here)248(more here)";
preg_match("/\(([^\)]*)\)/", $sTest, $aMatches);
$sResult = $aMatches[1];
```

But I don't know how to instruct PHP to read the specific brackets after a certain number.

Does anyone have any suggestions please?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds to me like a major Database Design Error. Maybe you should take a quick look at a tutorial on how to design a relational database

Comment: Why not just pass it as a part of the pattern? Like `preg_match("/\b" . $id . "\(([^)]*)\)/", $sTest, $aMatches);`?

Comment: You have to add your data in json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While redesigning the DB might look like a fix, a current work around is to pass the ID of the bracketed data as part of the regex pattern.

Consider [this snippet](https://ideone.com/r14MQn):

```
$id = 248;
$sTest = "247(text goes here)248(more here)";
preg_match("/\b" . $id . "\(([^\)]*)\)/", $sTest, $aMatches);
$sResult = $aMatches[1];
echo $sResult;
```

Here, `\b` is a word boundary to match a number as a whole word (so as not to match `1` in `21`) and `$id` becomes part of the pattern (but since you only get the contents of the first capturing group with `$aMatches[1]`, it is only used as context, and not part of  the extraction).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! This is perfect. DB redesign is definitely on the cards, but as an inherited situation, we needed a temporary solution to allow for time. I really appreciate your help, thank you!